# Runtime Class reference Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

If I have an interface named

```
interface ApiService
```

It is being called in my code as

```
ApiService::class.java
```

I understand that this `::class.java` a runtime java class reference, but how am I able to reference a java class at runtime with an interface?

To elaborate further  that class above is wrapped inside

```
getService()
```

Which takes as a parameter (Class someClass), so does Kotlin not consider the differences between a class and interface?

Comment: [*Instances of the class `Class` represent classes **and interfaces** in a running Java application.*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there's no difference between an `interface` and a `class` in this context: you can reference them in the same way. Note that this is not `kotlin` only, but it works the same way in `java`, as a `Class` is used to represent both classes and interfaces (see [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html))